# How do I mathematically treat a photon interacting with a potential?

Tags: photons

(My background: PhD Student, have taken many quantum mechanics courses, but not QFT yet).

Hello, 
In quantum mechanics for massive particles such as an electron, when the electron is in the presence of a potential $\hat{V}$, you would simply plug the expression for the potential into Schrodingers equation. But how would you treat a photon interacting with a potential? I have done some reading and found out that the Schrodinger equation is not valid for the photon and that Maxwell's equations are the way to go.  But I do not know how to incorporate an interaction potential when using Maxwell's equations.

Would it be at ALL correct in any respect to write the Hamiltonian in terms of a relativistic kinetic energy?  This can be written as $T=\sqrt{p^2c^2+m_0^2c^4}$.  For a photon $m_0=0$ and in the absence of any interaction potential, one has for the hamiltonian, $\hat{H}=c \hat{p}$. That way, when the photon interacts with a potential, I can simply write the Schrodinger equation as

$(\hat{H}+\hat{V})|\vec{k},\mu>=E|\vec{k},\mu>$

Where $|\vec{k},\mu>$ is the state of a photon traveling in the direction $\vec{k}$ with spin $\mu$.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Photons don't interact with potentials, so there is no equation for your purpose. You can learn how to perform quantum electrodynamics calculations... but that won't give you any potentials, either, I am afraid... for what it's worth:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quantum_electrodynamics#Equations_of_motion

Comment: I'm curious to know what kind of potential you are envisioning? Since photons are electromagnetically neutral they don't feel the electromagnetic force (at least to first aproximation).

Comment: A potential would imply a force.  Gravity is the only force that photons "feel."    You have to go to general relativity to study that and there they will tell you that its really not a force, just geometry,